# Como capturar UTC com uma aplicação Android

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde a todos!

Preciso capturar, através de um aplicativo android, qual o UTC usado no aparelho do cliente para fazer umas validações internas.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: O que quer dizer com "qual o UTC"?

Comment: É com relação ao fuso horário

Comment: Ve se o http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ te ajuda

Comment: Obrigado +Igor pelo link, vou dar uma olhada aqui! Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Use a classe [TimeZone.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html)

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
String name = timeZone.getID();
```

O método [getDefault()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) retorna o TimeZone que o dispositivo está a usar.
O método [getID()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getID()) retorna o seu ID, por exemplo `Portugal` ou `Brazil/East`.

Comment: Obrigado +ramaral vou implementar e realizar alguns testes!

Comment: Você aceitou a resposta do Edson, no entanto fiquei sem saber se o que procurava era o que eu respondi ou o respondido por ele.

Comment: Vou realizar os testes ainda, aceitei as duas por questão de "pendência", pois ainda não sei qual vai dar certo pra mim!

Comment: Você não consegue aceitar as duas ao mesmo tempo. Faça os seus testes e depois volte para escolher. Lembro que além de aceitar pode votar nas respostas.

Comment: Ahh ok então, obrigado pela dica! Não tinha esse conhecimento.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Date currentTime = new Date();
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("UTC time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

Comment: Edson, poderia fazer uma explicação sobre sua resposta ? Ela está entrando para a lista de **Publicações de baixa qualidade**.

Comment: Obrigado +Edson vou implementar e realizar uns testes!!